# forgot to do a fork on GitHub before starting my work

Tags: github

Suppose I clone Company C's repo of Project X from github to my local machine.  I create a branch for myself locally, do some work on it and make commits to my branch locally.

Now I want to make a pull request to Company C, but I realize that I should have done a fork on gitub to create my own repo of Project X and cloned that instead of Company C's repo.

How do I recover from this without cloning my fork locally and starting over by copying files manually?  I'd like to use git's magic to save myself.

Comment: I think this represents a UX flaw in github... many times people clone directly from a gihub repo (instead of making a clone first) just because they *think* they won't be making any changes to it. Then they run into a problem and start making commits to fix it (without remembering to go back and make a clone first)

Answer (score 14):

If you want to follow the development of the project you've cloned, by convention, we add another remote (named `upstream`) in addition to your `origin` remote.

So you have to:

1. Fork the project on **Github.com** website.
2. Rename the current `origin` remote (that tracks at the moment the upstream project) with a new name like `upstream`.

   ```
    git remote rename origin upstream
   ```
3. Add your personal forked GitHub project as the `origin` remote.

   ```
    git remote add origin <URL of your personal github fork>
   ```

The idea behind that is to follow the naming conventions of:

- `origin` for your personal repository
- `upstream` for the project repository (to be able to sync your personal repository with developments made in the upstream repository)

Comment: So I don't have to change the local branch of the original repo, because it tracks the remote by name ("remote")?

Comment: the convention is to have the remote `origin` to track the repository from which you cloned. At the moment it's the one of the upstream project. And because you want to modify as if you have cloned your personal repository, you must change to track your repository with `origin` and the upstream repository with `upstream` that way you follow the conventions which is always better...

Comment: I come back to this answer few times a year. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add your fork as a remote in your existing clone:

```
git remote add <any name> <URL of fork>
```

You may also want to `git remote rm` the original repo.

Comment: But my local branch's parent is already a tracking branch of the original repo

Comment: You can change it to track the new remote.

Answer (score 0):

The overall strategy is as follows:

1. See which remote repos are connected to your local repo
2. Disconnect the remote repos from your local repos.
3. Connect the desired remote repository to your local.

---

```
git remote -v #shows you the names of the remote repos
git remote remove {Name of the remote repo(s)}
git remote add {url of the desired remote repo}
```